# How to write the output to console and file?

Tags: java, io, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I have to output the method sayHello() twice.
The output should be written to the console, and once in a file.
I wrote some code but I don't get ahead.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class Utility {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try(OutputStream src = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/baum/Documents/TestText.txt");
        InputStream dest = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/baum/Documents/TestText.txt")){
        sayHello(src, dest);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

    public static void sayHello(OutputStream src, InputStream dest)throws IOException{

        String t = "Hello World!!!";
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(src);
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(dest);

        out.write(t.toCharArray());

        out.flush();
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: So if your going to output to the console, all you need is a print statement in your sayHello() method...

Comment: BTW You can do `out.write(t);` which is more efficient than `out.write(t.toCharArray());` You can also do `System.out.println(t);` to write to the console as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try {
    for (String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:\\path\\to\\text.txt"))) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

That's maybe a better way